# Cannot download html (entire web page)

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download the entire html code from

> http://www.ivolatility.com/options/AMZN/NASDAQ/

The output does not include the data in the tables.

This is the code I am using

```
url = 'http://www.ivolatility.com/options/AMZN/NASDAQ/'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('C:.../Downloads/amzn.html', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

I think it might be related to registration issues.

Anything I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request returns a login form, which means you'll have to login in order to access the data.

The login process is relatively easy - all we have to do is submit the form data to the login page (and use a `session` object to store the cookies).
Then we can use that authenticated session to retrieve the table contents.

The code,

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.ivolatility.com/options/AMZN/NASDAQ/'
login_url = 'https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j'
usr = 'my username'
pwd = 'my password'
data = {
    'username':usr, 'password':pwd,
    'ref_url':login_url, 'service_name':'Home Page', 
    'step':1, 'login__is__sent':1
    }

s = requests.session()
s.post(login_url, data)
r = s.get(url)

with open('my file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```